# use-defined conversion to array reference

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, type-deduction

```
template <typename T>
struct id
{
    typedef T type;
};

class S{
public:

    template<typename T, int N> 
    operator typename id<T(&)[N]>::type ();

};

void f(int(&)[20]) {}
void g(S s) { cout << typeid(f(s)).name(); }
```

gcc compile always error:
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int (&)[20]' from expression of type 'S'

why this failed?

Answer (score 3):

In `typename id<T(&)[N]>::type`, `T` and `N` are in a non-deduced context. Use an alias template instead:

```
template <typename T>
using id = T;

class S{
public:
    template<typename T, int N> 
    operator id<T(&)[N]> ();
};
```

Comment: Is there a non-C++11 solution?

Comment: Why are trailing-return-types not permitted for conversion functions? It's clear that operator auto is reserved for other use, but the trailing-return-type variant does not seem to impede any of that.